# How can I redirect old domain to new domain with htaccess in this special format

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect a subdomain to another like this with htaccess:

```
sub.old-domain.com
sub.old-domain.com/2016/02/test-blogpost/
sub.old-domain.com/category/test-category/
```

to:

```
sub.new-domain.com
```

So that every request of the old domain will be redirected to the new domain of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work (goes in .htaccess)

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.old-domain\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://sub\.new-domain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```